# What is the difference between a web server redirect and a hyperlink?

Tags: browser, redirection, terminology

When dealing with web browsers, both a *web server redirect* and a *hyperlink* can have the same destination (on the same web site or on another web site).

So, what is the difference between a web server redirect and a hyperlink?

Perhaps the difference is that moving between webpages with an hyperlink is voluntary and by web server redirect is non voluntary?

Comment: webserver redirect?  what do you mean?  can you give more info?  Are you talking about a .htaccess redirect?  or a redirect in the html code?

Comment: This question is nonsense as written.  A redirect is pushed by the server.  A hyperlink is whatever it is.  A redirect tells the browser to go elsewhere (via hyperlink).  A hyperlink does not.  Please elaborate on what you aren't understanding.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between a 301 redirect to a hyperlink. Both are page changing while the first one is nonvoluntary and the second one is voluntary.

Answer (score 0):

A Hyperlink is handled by the browser. upon click, the browser looks up the site IP address, and sends a `GET` request to that url. its a one-step process.

A Redirect however is involves the server. it requires multiple steps, but the redirection occurs automatically.

1. the browser requests a URL that has been redirected on the server.
2. The server sends a `301` or `302` response, and includes the url that the browser should use instead.
3. The browser makes a request to the new URL.